# Automatically assign Google Groups to Airflow roles in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Google Cloud Composer instance (v2) whose configuration is managed by Terraform and whose dags are in the format:

```
dags/
  foo/
    dag_1.py
    dag_2.py
  bar/
    dag_3.py
    dag_4.py
```

In the corresponding Airflow environment I automatically create [per-folder registration](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/airflow-rbac#how_per-folder_roles_registration_works) roles that limit access to dags in other folders, so for this case I have a role `foo` that only lets users view/run/etc. `dag_1.py` and `dag_2.py`, and role `bar` which only lets users view/run/etc. `dag_3.py` and `dag_4.py`.

I also have two google groups `foo_users@example.com` and `bar_users@example.com`. I would like it so that anytime a new user in one of those groups enters the Airflow UI, they are automatically given the permission that lets them view their corresponding subfolder. From the docs it appears google groups [cannot be preregistered](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/airflow-rbac#preregister-users).

Is there a way around this limitation to do what I want, like a custom IAM role? I would prefer not to have to run the gcloud command referenced in the above docs each time to grant individual users a role (there will be many users here). Thanks!